# angular 2- http response 401 error on session call

Tags: typescript, angular2-services, angular2-directives, http-status-code-401, http-error

i am new to angular 2. I am calling getSession() method in the response of login but it still gives me unauthorized user error and i don't understand what is the reason behind this error. here is my code *login.ts* is the component and *user-service.ts* is the service i am calling in login.ts to get session.

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { SignupPage } from '../signup/signup';
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',

})
export class LoginPage {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    invalidCredentials;
    signupPage = SignupPage;
    user = { username: "", password: "" };
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, private userService: UserServiceProvider) {
        this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
            emailAddress: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.email, Validators.required])],
            password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(4), Validators.required])]
        });
    }

    loginUser() {

         this.userService.login(this.user.username, this.user.password)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.getSession();
                this.invalidCredentials = false;
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage)
            }, err => {
                this.invalidCredentials = true;
            }
            );

    }
getSession() {     

      this.userService.getSessionFromServer().subscribe(data=> {
         console.log("getsesion");

            },err=>{

                console.log("err");
            });


    }
}
```

**user-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SettingServiceProvider } from '../../providers/setting-service/setting-service';
import { LoginPage } from '../../pages/login/login';

@Injectable()
export class UserServiceProvider {
  session: any;
  constructor(public http: Http, private settingServiceProvider: SettingServiceProvider ) {

  }
  login(username: string, password: string): any {
    var creds = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post(this.settingServiceProvider.setting().baseUrl + 'login', creds,
      { headers: headers }
    );
  }

      getSessionFromServer(){
        return this.http.get(this.settingServiceProvider.setting().baseUrl + "session")
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
    }

}
```

Thankyou in advance